# How to update CoreData data using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

In myscenario, I am storing popupVC textfield `title` and `descript` values into CoreData. Once, stored Data into CoreData then fetching data into UITableView. Each and every Tableview cell I am having edit button within `editActionsForRowAt`. Once, user clicked the edit button I am passing the `EditpopupVC.task = self.userData[indexPath.row]`.  In EditpopupVC I am receiving the values like `var task: NSManagedObject? = nil`. Now, After modification of data if user click update button then I am calling `func update(title: String, descript: String) { }` for passed particular value update.

**Edit Button Click to Passing data from ListViewController to EditpopupVC**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
        print("Edit tapped")
        let task = self.userData[indexPath.row]
        let EditpopupVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editviewcontroller") as! EditViewController
        EditpopupVC.titlename = "Edit"
        EditpopupVC.task = self.userData[indexPath.row]
        EditpopupVC.modalTransitionStyle   = .crossDissolve
        EditpopupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        self.present(EditpopupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    return [editAction]
}
```

**Once User Modified Text Data then Update button click to Calling Update Function**

```
update(title: Titletextfield.text ?? "Empty", descript: Descriptiontextview.text)
```

**CoreData Update Function I am using Below**

```
func update(title: String, descript: String) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    task.title = title
    task.descript = descript
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("Could not save. \(error)")
    }
}
```

`EditpopupVC.task = self.userData[indexPath.row]` This line helping to pass the array of Data to `EditpopupVC`.

Comment: where you called this `update(indexPath:` method

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik if user modify text and click update button I am calling the `update(indexPath:`.

Comment: can you show the code and where you called the edit button target in your tableview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Edit button I placed into `editActionsForRowAt` Within `let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, indexPath) in` I am calling `let updateVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "updateVC")`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Updated Question. please check it!

Comment: your self.updateTitles and tasks count is same or different

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I will check and let you know here.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik In popupVC I declared `var task: NSManagedObject? = nil` `var indexPathForTask: IndexPath? = nil` and `var tasks: [NSManagedObject] = []` I think value is not same.

Comment: are you intersted watching video on hindi..? so i can send video link all about coredata that solve your issue.

Comment: @YogeshPatel Sure. Share your link here. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Great Please watch my coredata series :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTtYSJtVKMc&list=PLWZIhpNhtvfofDMgWtuknkcow-_jY-dfa
i am sure this videos are helpful for you. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data objects are reference types, you don't need to assign the object back to the array.

The crash occurs because you don't set `tasks` in the `popupVC` so it remains empty and raises a out-of-range exception.

In the main controller declare `updateTitles` with a more specific type

```
var updateTitles = [Myrecord]()
```

In `popupVC` delete `tasks`, declare task as

```
var task : Myrecord!
```

and  replace `update` with

```
func update(title: String, descript: String) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    task.title = title
    task.descript = descript
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Could not save. \(error)")
    }
}
```

the index path is not needed.

When the controller disappears reload the table view.

---

Side note:

Force unwrapping `AppDelegate` is fine. Without `AppDelegate` the application won't even launch.

Comment: Great help and very useful information `index path is not needed`. Thank you so much. I will try my side and update it mark here.

Comment: above solution not overwriting. it is creating new record.

Comment: This code does not create a new record. You create the record somewhere else in the controller.

Comment: Getting error `Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '(String, forKey: String)'` at `task.setValue(title, forKey: "title")` and `task.setValue(descript, forKey: "descript")`

Comment: You should use the `NSManagedObject` subclass (the entity class) and dot notation `task.title = "title")`.

Comment: `let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MyRecord", in: managedObjectContext) else { return }
        let task = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
        task.setValue(title, forKey: "title")
        task.setValue(descript, forKey: "descript")` This is I am using but getting new record.

Comment: This is completely different code. `NSManagedObject(entity:insertInto:`does create a new record. Please edit the question to show the exact code you are using

Comment: Again Getting error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` at `task.title = title`

Comment: This is impossible if you run the line in the question `updateVC.task = self.updateTitles[indexPath.row]`